# Struggling to breathe in old home is it alright to keep my room vent closed?

Tags: hvac

I recently moved to Columbus Ohio into a home that is incredibly old possibly 100+ years.  I had found it and my roomates online and I’ve been happy with situation but my asthma and allergies have been absolutely horrible since to the point that it’s debilitating.  There were gaps between wall and floor boards that my landlords have since filled which I think may have made a difference but I’m also on cortisone steroids because of how bad it had gotten (this is a short term emergency solution to be able to breathe and not a long term one).  I also closed my vent in desperation but have since read this could potentially lead to mold (if I’m honest I think that might be the case already but don’t want to make the problem worse) I ordered an air purifier but I’m concerned about the air vents and was wondering if I should open them back up.  I’m actually moving from my current room to one that is twice the size in the same home (one small room that leads to another small room with an open door way). Each small room has an  air vent - one that seems in fine condition and the other that is quite dirty(this specific one was closed by my previous roomate and I don’t know for how long I suspect it might have mold) and is on the wall that is shared with our bathroom. Our bathroom doesn’t have a fan so I’m concerned about humidity playing a role in mold growth so close by (the vent is visibly dirty in the bathroom and there seems to be black surrounding which is kind of terrifying me.  I’m hoping to clean it and the ones in my room after some research on how to do so correctly).  I’m hoping to save up for a dehumidifier for both the bathroom and my room eventually but was wondering if leaving the dirty vent in my room closed would help or hurt the situation.  I’m also concerned about actually needing the heat as it can get so cold here and eventually the ac as I’ve heard it can be very hot in other months.  I was hoping to leave it closed so that my air purifier could really help but am nervous that’s misguided.  Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: 100 years is well within credibility. I can walk to a couple that are pushing 250, and anyone in Asia or Europe can find 500-1000 year old ones without a lot of effort. Or lives in one.

Comment: Some editing would make this easier to read.

Comment: Unless you have water running on the walls, or at last noticeably damp walls you shouldn't be that worried about mold. A dirty vent isn't really going to affect you - if the dirt is on the vent if not going to you unless something disturbs it, otherwise it just sits there.